# Input String was not in the correct format error c#

Tags: c#

I am inserting values from a database into a chart.. I am pulling the data from 2 columns,
the first column  contains String values ( Mixture of letters, numbers and spaces) and the second column contains float values (Just numeric types) .
When ever I run the query I keep getting this error: "Input String was not in the correct format" Can some one help me pls?

```
try { 
    Query = "SELECT * FROM Products;";
    Reader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);

    while (Reader.Read()) { 
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.
        AddXY((Double.Parse(Regex.Replace(Reader.GetString(1),@"[^\d|\.]",""))),
        (Convert.ToDouble(Reader.GetInt32(4))));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}

conn.CloseConnection();
```

Comment: Change `ex.Message` to `ex.ToString()` and provide us with the full exception.

Comment: here is the error:  System.formatException:Input string was not in a correct format.at System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormationInfo numfmt) at System.Single.Parse(String s)

Comment: Are you sure that the columns returned by the SQL query are in the correct order?

Comment: is solution work for you ???

Comment: Do you need to pass in the correct culture to parse the string, as Parse uses the current culture? If your local culture has different requirements for decimals that the data, then you may need to pass a different format provider in, e.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 2):

This is a data issue. Either `Reader.GetString(1)` or `Reader.GetString(4)` is returning something that cannot be parsed or converted to `double`.

Instead of relying on `SELECT * FROM Products`, list the column names and be sure to select from the proper columns.